# can docker overwrite PATH for macos?

Tags: node.js, docker, macos, nvm

I am having a problem with PATH. Every time I run docker compose and stop containers I no longer can for example run `node -v` or `nvm -v`. Restarting computer does not help. I always have to run something like `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`. I assume docker somehow overwrites bash_profile. Can docker do that ?

Comment: Docker won't interfere with the host's `$PATH` at all.  A container normally contains a single application and its runtime, so the `FROM` line of the Dockerfile should say which Node to use, and you shouldn't need a version manager like `nvm`.  Docker also won't interfere with _e.g._ `brew install node` on the host system.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], showing what you're doing with Docker and what sequence of commands fail?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are adding some volumes that expose bash_profile or profile or .bashrc files to the container and the container then modifies them.

The problem lies in your docker based application. Please revise that.

Docker by itself does not change PATH. it will add its own binaries to /bin which is on the PATH.